# How do I add a mean and standard deviation line to a barchart as specified in the picture? [SPSS]

Tags: graph, error-handling, element, spss

I need to format a graph that sort of looks like this:

Showcase Mittelwert=Mean
[image: Showcase Mittelwert=Mean]

This is how far I got but I always get an error and/or it doesn't work:

```
GGRAPH /GRAPHDATASET NAME="graphdataset" VARIABLES=q5211 COUNT()[name="COUNT"] MISSING=LISTWISE 
    REPORTMISSING=NO   /GRAPHSPEC SOURCE=INLINE.
BEGIN GPL
  SOURCE: s=userSource(id("graphdataset"))
  DATA: q5211=col(source(s), name("q5211"))
  DATA: COUNT=col(source(s), name("COUNT"))
  GUIDE: axis(dim(1), label("q521.1 To what extent do you think that freedom to express opinions ",
    "is guaranteed in your country?"))
  GUIDE: axis(dim(2), label("Prozent"))
ELEMENT: interval(position(summary.percent(q5211*COUNT, base.all(acrossPanels()))), 
    shape.interior(shape.square))
ELEMENT: interval(position(summary.mean(q5211, base.all(acrossPanels()))))
ELEMENT: interval(position(summary.mean(q5211, base.all(acrossPanels()))))
END GPL.
```

This is the error I get for this:

```
76 GGraph GPL-Fehler: summary.mean(q5211,base.all(acrossPanels()))

Arguments [q5211, base.all([acrossPanels([])])] are unexpected by (required=[Density])
```

Comment: Also search [stats.stackexchange](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spss) for SPSS questions.

Comment: If you add a reproducible example I can post an example graph much quicker.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I've actually seen some of your tutorials on my search for help. For the example one can use whatever variable that has five categories. Or maybe I don't understand how to do a reproducible sample in SPSS, maybe you could point me to what you need specifically? Some help would be much appreciated!

Comment: The idea behind a reproducible example is to make a set of data that looks like yours and I can run your code on. See [here for some examples in SPSS](https://andrewpwheeler.wordpress.com/2012/03/20/making-a-reproducible-example-in-spss/). The chart you linked to is not in English - so I'm not 100% sure what it is showing. What are the vertical bars supposed to represent? Is the black error bar a mean and plus and minus two standard deviations?

Comment: I am very sorry for replying so late. 

So I took a look at your reproducible example and basically just copied the "mycat" example, I have a bunch of variable with 5 categories that need to be graphed in the same way.

This is the code:


set seed = 10.
input program.
loop #j = 1 to 100.
    loop #i = 1 to 100. 
    compute exam = TRUNC(RV.UNIFORM(0,5))..
    end case.
    end loop.
end loop.
end file.
end input program.
dataset name sim.
execute.

Comment: So basically all I need is a barchart where the y-Axis would be in percent and in addition there is a line or point indicating the mean of the variable and an error bar that shows plus and minus two standard deviations of the mean (as you said). Is that generally possible?